# What is the exact bus protocol used by the C64/C128 REU?

Tags: commodore-64, commodore-128, dma

The Commodore 64/128 [RAM Expansion Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_REU)s used a DMA controller
to move data between the REU's RAM and system RAM (or I/O space). One
would set the addreses, length and direction for the transfer (or
verify) operation and trigger it; the CPU would then be "paused" while
the DMA controller took over the bus to do the transfer, with the CPU
resuming when the transfer was complete. (The REU DMA unit would also
handle the situation where DMA had to be paused so the VIC-II video
chip could access memory during what were normally "CPU" memory
cycles.)

I'm guessing, based on the schematics in the [C64/C64C Service
Manual](https://www.retro-kit.co.uk/user/custom/Commodore/C64/manuals/C64C_Service_Manual.pdf), that this worked something along the lines of the
DMA controller asserting `D̅M̅A̅` on the cartridge port, which will bring
the CPU's `RDY` ("pause CPU") and `CAEC` (CPU "address enable
control," tristating the address/data buses and `R/W̅`) lines low when
the VIC-II is asserting `BA` ("bus available," also on the cartridge
port) and its `AEC` line, at which point the DMA controller could do
its thing (pausing when the VIC-II needs the bus) until completion,
then releasing `D̅M̅A̅`.

Does anybody know the exact details and timings of how this worked, or
have a reference to documentation describing this?

Comment: How did you get the overlines on `DMA` and `R/W`?

Comment: @DrSheldon I assume he's using the overline combining code - U305 - UTF-8 CC85 - decimal 773 - can be entered on (most) Win10 programs with ALT-0773. It's one of the [combining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) diacritical marks that modify the previous character for printing. To be taken with caution, as display across platforms and programs is inconsistent - they are the legal heir of 1980s 7-bit-mess. Not a great idea to use them when other accepted ways are available - especially on a place for old computers - as they produce rubbish on anything but the newest OS/machine.

Comment: @DrSheldon I use the Unicode [combining overline](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0305/index.htm) character. (I have a vim digraph for this: `digraph '/ 773`.) [My notes on this](https://github.com/0cjs/sedoc/blob/master/ee/README.md) give some further info and discuss various options for NOT. It works pretty well for me on a broad range of platforms (Android being the notable exception), and I like that it matches what I see all the time in data sheets, though of course Raffzahn never misses the chance to tell me I'm wrong about both of these points.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson It's about that things, that work for one user, may not execute everywhere  - in fact, not even within one system - like various (MS-supplied) windows tools show by using wrong width or placement of the line. Even more so when crossing systems - with the Android example being not the least. Long story short, its the same issue today, like back then with characters outside non variant ISO-646. While umlauts can be guessed by readers, any information carrying part (like hegation) must use basic encoding. A welcoming writing style should lean toward reaching all readers everywhere.

Comment: @Raffzahn A welcoming writing style should also stop constantly criticising others just because they do things in a way you don't personally like.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson This was an answer to Dr.Sheldon, not you. It was strictly about how I assumed you created the overstrike (which seamed to be correct) and a factual remark about that methods pitfalls. I see no way how they can be taken as anything personal. There is no 'dislike'. I do not like or dislike you, as we don't know each other. Interpreting a professional remark as personal is quite a stretch, isn't it? One that, is not really to the benefit of RC.SE. All I can do at this point is to ask you, please, reconsider and act sensible.

Comment: @Raffzahn _"I see no way how they can be taken as anything personal."_ And that, in a nutshell, is your problem. Becuase when I talk like you, you certainly take it personally. And no, _"Not a great idea to use them"_ is not a technical fact.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Sorry, but I really don't understand this. How is it possible for you to know better than me what I do take personal? That logic escapes me. My impression so far is that you seam take every view, which isn't exactly as you imagine as an attack on yourself. Sorry, but it isn't. I have neither time nor intention to play games. I'm simply i here to learn and exchange knowledge. I dare to judge you, as I don't know you. Thus, all I can do is asking you kindly , _please, take a step back, be reasonable and handle RC.SE the professional way it deserves_.

Comment: @Raffzahn _" I really don't understand this."_ Correct. You don't understand how you're being offensive, as I've told you and you've admitted many times before. However, you should by now understand that you _are_ being offensive, and when you ask me to fix what I'm doing (implicitly blaming the problem entirely on me), you make the problem worse. Try this: never comment on any of my posts. If something really needs correction, someone else will say it.

Comment: Gentlemen, I appreciate each of you answering my comment.  However, the discussion seems to have turned into personal attacks.  Perhaps it is time to stop that.

Comment: As DMA goes to both AEC and RDY at the same time, tri-stating a 3-cycle read operation can't be good? How could you time it to get in between instructions?
or the 6510 re-do a read instruction if it saw AEC go low? If you pull DMA low while BA+3cycles is low, you know VIC did a safe RDY. so now you just wait for BA to go high, and you start using the bus until next BA +3cycles.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic behavior is correctly stated in the question. However, the details of the timing have to account for the rather complicated details of how RDY works on the NMOS version 6502 *and* MOS 6510 (**Note**: 65C02 is different). From the data sheet from Commodore, it states:

> **Ready (RDY)** - This input signal allows the user to single cycle the microprocessor on all cycles **except write cycles.** A negative transition to the low state during or **coincident with phase one (01) and up to 100ns after phase two (02)** will halt the microprocessor with the output address lines reflecting the current address being fetched. This condition will remain through a subsequent phase two in which the Ready signal is low. This feature allows microprocessor interfacing with low speed PROMS as well as fast
> (max. 2 cycle) Direct Memory Access (DMA). **If Ready is low
> during a write cycle, it is ignored until the following read operation.**

So, besides what is specified for timing in the question, the critical bit is that you need to wait until a read cycle is being setup by the CPU.

In the case of the REU, this is implicit in how the device works. Since the DMA operation is triggered by the CPU writing to the I/O space (Command Register = $DF01), the following CPU operation would be to fetch the next instruction. So that guarantees a read is being setup by the CPU when the REU asserts D̅M̅A̅ during Phi2 low.

To summarize, D̅M̅A̅ should be asserted while Phi2 is low and BA is high, AND with the CPU pending a READ operation. Then, the DMA device (REU) is able to master the bus on the next Phi2 high cycle, and may continue to do so unless BA is removed. In that case, it has to wait on the VIC-II to reassert BA, and then continue. When the operation is done, the D̅M̅A̅ signal is removed by the device, and then the CPU continues with its read operation.

Comment: So I definitely have to wait for the right conditions after I assert `D̅M̅A̅`. Are there any timing restrictions on when I assert `D̅M̅A̅`, or can I just do that any time and wait?

Comment: Hi Curt. Just to be pedantic, you need to know a CPU read operation will be pending __before__ you assert it, OR be prepared to wait for the next read is pending to access the bus. Beyond that, the data sheet says assert during Phi1 and no later than 100ns after Phi2 rising edge. That's based on RDY, though. To allow some propagation delay, I'd assert the cartridge port DMA line by the middle of Phi1 (Phi2 LOW), if possible.

Comment: I've just come across Christian Bauer's [VIC-II document](http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/cbm/c64/vic-ii.txt) and I notice that it says in §2.4.3, "BA will then go low 3 cycles
before the VIC takes over the bus completely (3 cycles is the maximum
number of successive write accesses of the 6510)." This sounds to me as if you don't need to care about knowing exactly when a read operation will be pending; you can just bring `D̅M̅A̅` low any time and wait three cycles, which was roughly what I was getting at in my first comment. Is this correct, to your knowledge? Or is it not that simple?

Comment: A [recent post on forum.6502.org](http://forum.6502.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5861) seems to indicate that there are timing contstraints on when you can assert `RDY`: the [t<sub>PCS</sub> timing](http://forum.6502.org/download/file.php?id=8936&mode=view). But outside of that I don't see contstraints involving waiting for a read cycle to be set up for the CPU; it looks to me as if you can assert it as early as you like, and if you don't get in soon enough before a write cycle, you'll have to wait until the write cycle is completed, that's all.

Comment: See note above about the 65C02 being different. Also, the more critical bit with the 6510 is to not access the bus prematurely (before the write cycles are done). Not when you assert /DMA on the expansion port.

Comment: This was what I wanted to confirm: are there any constraints on when I can assert DMA on the expansion port, or can I just assert it any time, wait three full φ2 high/φ2 low cycles after that point, and be guaranteed safe?

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Yes, maximum of 3 write cycles *might* occur, and then the bus should be guaranteed available for DMA.

Comment: Perfect; that's exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: @BrianH: If /DMA is asserted during a write cycle, will the 6510 have control of the bus during that cycle, or would some random byte get written to some random address?

Comment: @supercat The 6510 will _assume_ it has control of the bus and finish the write cycle, per the datasheet. But the REU won't assert /DMA during write.

Comment: @BrianH: My point was that, from my understanding, external devices must refrain from asserting /DMA during a write. Asserting /DMA prematurely would likely result in memory corruption even if a device waits three cycles before trying to access the bus.

Comment: @supercat What is it about `D̅M̅A̅` that causes this issue? It doesn't seem to be `RDY` alone, since according to the 1985 [CSG NMOS
6500 Microprocessors data sheet](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6500_mpu_nov_1985.pdf), "If Ready is low
during a write cycle, it is ignored until the following read operation." (p.7) I'd say that bringing `AEC` low when the CPU is using the address bus is likely to cause problems, but that's not under direct control of `D̅M̅A̅` but is managed by the VIC II.

Comment: @cjs: By my understanding, the /DMA signal takes control of the bus away from the 6510 instantly.  If a device asserts READY, the 6510 will within 3.5 cycles stop caring about what happens on the bus, but it may be relying upon the bus to work normally during the three cycles after assertion.  Having control of the bus stolen from the 6510 while it is expecting to it to work normally will likely cause behavioral disruption or memory corruption.

Comment: @supercat I was asking how you knew that `D̅M̅A̅`  deasserted `AEC` immediately, as well as deasserting `RDY`. I had to go to the schematics to [confirm and explain this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23662/7208).