# Does C64 /DMA assertion immediately disconnect the CPU from the address bus?

Tags: commodore-64, dma

I have heard several claims (in the [comments on this question and
answers](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12739/7208)) that asserting the `D̅M̅A̅` signal on the Commodore C64
cartridge port will immediately take the CPU off the bus by deasserting its
`AEC` line. How does it do this?

Comment: If it's any consolation, the TRS-80 effectively does the same thing. If you try to assert the BUSREQ pin, the logic tri-states out all of the CPU busses immediately, rather than waiting for the BUSACK signal telling the requester that the Z80 has, indeed, given up the bus. In fact, the BUSACK signal isn't even made available anywhere. Good times.

Answer (score 4):

In all versions of the schematics from the [Commodore C64/C64C Service
Manual](https://www.retro-kit.co.uk/user/custom/Commodore/C64/manuals/C64C_Service_Manual.pdf), the `D̅M̅A̅` line proceeds from the cartridge port to:

1. A 3k3 pullup resisistor.
2. A 74LS08 AND gate with `BA` (a VIC signal) to CPU `RDY`.
3. A 74LS08 AND gate with "system" (i.e., not CPU) `AEC` generating `CAEC`
   to the CPU's `AEC` pin.
   [image: U27]   [image: U27 negative logic]

Thus bringing DMA low will immediately bring low one side of the AND gate
in 3 above, causing the output to be low and AEC to be deasserted on the
CPU. (The VIC-II chip may also independently deassert `CAEC` from the other
side of the gate; this is used for DRAM refresh, among other things.)

The implication here is that unlike just asserting `RDY`, which can safely
be pulled low any time,¹ one must be very careful of timing when asserting
`D̅M̅A̅`. The "deassert `RDY` and wait three cycles" strategy to avoid
conflicting with CPU write instructions isn't available here; you must keep
track of when the CPU is doing a write and avoid asserting `D̅M̅A̅` during
that time lest it disconnect the CPUs address lines while it's completing a
write sequence.

---

<sub>¹ [CSG NMOS 6500 Microprocessors](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6500_mpu_nov_1985.pdf) (1985) data sheet, p.7: "If
Ready is low during a write cycle, it is ignored until the following read
operation."</sub>

Comment: At first I though the two illustrations of 74LS08 gates were of the gates for points 2 and 3, but they're actually two examples of the third point (from different schematic diagrams).

Comment: One may safely use the approach of driving RDY low and assuming the CPU will release the bus within three cycles, *but one would need to refrain from asserting /DMA during those three cycles*.

Comment: @supercat Not on an (unmodified) C64, as far as I can see. The only connection to the CPU's `RDY` pin is the output of the gate in connection 2, which can only be brought low by asserting `D̅M̅A̅`, which will also disconnect the CPU's address bus per connection 3. (`BA` is connected to the other input of the gate in connection 2, but that's an output from the PLA.)

Comment: @cjs: Hmm... I guess I'd blindly assumed an external wire would be available to trigger RDY.  A lot of bus connectors seem to make some curious decisions.